# Inside of classes .grid_rowconfigure() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am creating a GUI based Python game. I have a class for every frame that I am using, but when I set the rows and columns so that they scale with the window, nothing happens. The code executes, but it doesn't do what it should do. I am very new to the coding scene, and after researching for a few hours, I could not find a solution.

I have looked around this site and other places on Google for an answer. I have tested what I coded outside of classes and frames and it all worked. Adding that stuff back in again made it not work.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()
#This is the starting page
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        label_1 = Label(self,text="I exist", font=('Courier', 30))
        label_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        label_2 = Label(self, text="Pick a way to play", font=('Courier', 15))
        label_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        button_1 = Button(self, text="New Game", fg='black', bg='green', width=25, command=lambda: root.switch_frame(PlayerInfo))
        button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        button_2 = Button(self, text="Load Game", fg='black', bg='yellow', width=25, command=lambda: root.switch_frame(LoadGame))
        button_2.grid(row=1, column=2)
        button_3 = Button(self, text='Exit Game', fg='black', bg='red', width=25, command=lambda: sys.exit())
        button_3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        label_3 = Label(self, text='')
        label_3.grid(row=1, column=1)
        label_4 = Label(self, text='')
        label_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
        label_5 = Label(self, text='')
        label_5.grid(row=2, column=2)
#Here is the configuring problem
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
class PlayerInfo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Label(self, text='Game will start').pack()
class LoadGame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Label(self, text='Load old game').pack()
#Run it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

I understand how to use .grid_rowconfigure(), however when using it inside of a class it just hasn't been doing anything at all. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `grid_rowconfigure()`, but rather how you `pack` your frame. Your frame occupies only the space it needs to, and so even your window expands it stays the same.

To have the frame also expands, pass two more parameters to your `pack` method:

```
self._frame.pack(expand=True,fill="both")
```